# Recover persistent vm queue on Mule ESB application startup

Tags: mule

I was trying out the vm transport with persistent queues; this is the connector config:

```
<vm:connector 
        name="vmConnector"
        createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true"
        numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="20">
    <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="50000">
        <file-queue-store/>
    </vm:queue-profile>
</vm:connector>
```

Transport works fine and transports, .msg files are accumulating in the appropriate subdirectory of .mule. Now, if i kill the VM (or do a regular shutdown of the mule instance) and then restart mule and my application, i would expect consumption of the messages currently on the queue to resume, but it does not.

Have I understood something wrong? I thought this behaviour would be the one reason to use persistent queues at all. Or is my configuration faulty? This is all I could glean from the documentation, but I might have missed something.

EDIT: On further inspection, I found the following complaints in my application logs:

```
WARN  TransactionalQueueManager [THREAD vmConnector.scheduler.03 THREAD]: Could not commit tx 768d9b5c-ab3a-11e1-a48f-ff62aff02664[committing], rolling back instead
org.mule.util.xa.ResourceManagerException: Deleting ...\mule-enterprise-standalone-3.2.2\.mule\myapp\queuestore\work\0-768b784b-ab3a-11e1-a48f-ff62aff02664.msg failed (org.mule.api.store.ObjectStoreException)
    at org.mule.util.queue.QueueTransactionContext.doCommit(QueueTransactionContext.java:201)
    at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.doCommit(TransactionalQueueManager.java:173)
    at org.mule.util.xa.AbstractResourceManager.commitTransaction(AbstractResourceManager.java:288)
    at org.mule.util.xa.DefaultXASession.commit(DefaultXASession.java:83)
    at org.mule.transport.vm.VMTransaction.doCommit(VMTransaction.java:59)
    at org.mule.transaction.AbstractTransaction.commit(AbstractTransaction.java:82)
    at org.mule.transaction.AbstractSingleResourceTransaction.commit(AbstractSingleResourceTransaction.java:78)
    at org.mule.transaction.TransactionTemplate.resolveTransaction(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
    at org.mule.transaction.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:117)
    at org.mule.transport.TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.poll(TransactedPollingMessageReceiver.java:138)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:219)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:85)
    at org.mule.transport.ContinuousPollingReceiverWorker.poll(ContinuousPollingReceiverWorker.java:36)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:767)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:658)
    at org.mule.work.ScheduleWorkExecutor.doExecute(ScheduleWorkExecutor.java:41)
    at org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager.executeWork(MuleWorkManager.java:250)
    at org.mule.work.MuleWorkManager.scheduleWork(MuleWorkManager.java:208)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorkerSchedule.run(PollingReceiverWorkerSchedule.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.mule.api.store.ObjectStoreException: Deleting ...\mule-enterprise-standalone-3.2.2\.mule\myapp\queuestore\work\0-768b784b-ab3a-11e1-a48f-ff62aff02664.msg failed
    at org.mule.util.store.QueuePersistenceObjectStore.deleteStoreFile(QueuePersistenceObjectStore.java:310)
    at org.mule.util.store.QueuePersistenceObjectStore.doRemove(QueuePersistenceObjectStore.java:295)
    at org.mule.util.store.AbstractObjectStore.remove(AbstractObjectStore.java:91)
    at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.doRemove(TransactionalQueueManager.java:191)
    at org.mule.util.queue.QueueTransactionContext.doCommit(QueueTransactionContext.java:193)
    ... 30 more
```

The mentioned file does indeed still exist.

Comment: At first glance, it feels like a bug. Mule version? Do you see the persisted messages before restart?

Comment: Version is 3.2.2 EE; and I can confirm seeing the .msg files in the queuestore subdir while the jvm is down, and seeing them stay there after restart. I also finally looked into the logs, and found the stacktraces I added above.

Comment: EE? I suggest you contact MuleSoft support directly then.

Comment: We're still evaluating, so that is that. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known bug](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6102) and has been fixed for 3.2.3 EE and 3.3.0 CE.